# Set Chrome font

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, fonts

An hour ago my Google Chrome crashed. When I started it again it had a messed-up font.

Original Chrome font:

[image: [Here][1] is the original Chrome font, and]

What is looks like now:

[image: [here][2] is what it looks like now.]

The font on actual webpages is not changed, so I can't fix it with an extension. It's the Chrome bookmarks, tab titles and search bar textbox that are messed up. I played around in Settings for a bit but to no avail.

What should I do?

Comment: @DavidPostill I think it looks clearer with the images as links, can we leave it like that?

Comment: *shrug*. I think the inlined images are better. Normally we inline image to save readers from clicking elsewhere to understand the question.

Comment: @DavidPostill Okay. I'm just worried because the font in the second image is too small to see. But if a reader cares, they can click on it and get a larger image. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Same happened to me on Windows 10. Yesterday everything was great. Today fonts got like 1.5 times smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start -> "Change window colors and metrics"

[image: wca]

Set the Item dropdown to "Menu", then the "Font" dropdown to "Segoe UI". Click Apply and restart Chrome. This will definitely fix the search bar's font and usually fixes tabs' font  (but sometimes extensions/themes will screw this up).

Comment: What about Windows 10?

Comment: @nikoliazekter Question was tagged [tag:windows-7], I see no need to provide an answer for Windows 10.

Comment: Yeah, but I got the same problem today and wondered if you know the solution for Windows 10.

Comment: @nikoliazekter Nope, sorry. Never used or been interested in 8/10 :P